# Como borrar un Id y reestructurar la base de datos

Tags: php, sql

tengo el siguiente problema y no se si hay una función en **php** para hacer esto o de que forma puedo solucionarlo.

Tengo una base de datos en la cual voy a buscar registros que coincidan con un criterio de búsqueda, al recibirlo tendré algo así:

```
id  total  pagado
1   $100   1
3   $400   1
7   $500   1
```

quiero eliminar esos registros, pero tengo que dejar los ID consecutivos, y estos en la búsqueda serán salteados, de que forma lo puedo hacer con PHP, hay alguna función o función que conozcan ?

*Saludos!*

Comment: ¿Exactamente para qué quieres dejar los identificadores consecutivos? ¿Hay otras tablas que hagan referencia a esos registros a través de ese identificador? Hacer lo que dices es muy sencillo, pero si es el motivo es otro (visual, por ejemplo) quizá sea mejor otra solución.

Comment: Podrías explicar un poco más lo que quieres conseguir y/o exponer un ejemplo del resultado que esperas. Y si es posible explicar el motivo para hacerlo. Esto ayudará a que te podamos dar una respuesta más concreta y acorte a tu problema. Ya que las respuestas obtenidas deberían se utilizadas en casos muy concretos por que son destructivas  y pueden causar problemas, si no se sabe lo que se hace.

Comment: ¿Has consultado las respuestas para ver si alguna satisface tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar esto:

```
ALTER TABLE companies
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
CHANGE id id int(11),
ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);
```

Mas o menos esa es la idea, deberías eliminar la columna ID actual y luego volver a crear una nueva columna id, en ejemplo uuid, como primary key y autoincrement.

Espero ayude saludos.

Comment: Me funciono bien, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

La solución podría pasar por eliminar el campo `id` completamente y volver a agregarlo como `AUTOINCREMENT` para que éste se reordene con nuevos valores.

El problema que veo es que si los valores de ese campo son referenciados desde otras tablas tendrás problemas con la integridad relacional.

Para llevar a cabo la tarea descrita necesitarás ejecutar:

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP id;
ALTER TABLE test
  ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo en línea del funcionamiento en el [siguiente enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rvQYJDQkPn7JJABCnaUJVz/0).

Hay otras alternativas:

- Decrementar los valores superiores a los eliminados en uno para compactar cada elemento eliminado.
- Rellenar los elementos eliminados asignando ese valor al registro que contiene el valor actual máximo.

Pero todas estas soluciones son, a mi parecer, malas ideas si luego queremos referenciar los registros de manera inequívoca a través de ese campo (y si no es así, quizá no tenga sentido agregarlo).